# Boost Error: resolve: Host not found (authoritative) code from example not working

Tags: c++, http, networking, boost, centos

I'm compiling the code from this page:
https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_77_0/libs/beast/doc/html/beast/quick_start/http_client.html
However no matter what I pass as arguments `./client www.example.com 80 /` or
`./client www.google.com 80 /` the code never works and it throws the error I wrote in title.
I noticed I can't run the `resolver.resolve(resolver_query);` code with any arguments:

```
boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query resolver_query{"google.com", ""};
boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query resolver_query2{"google.com", "80"};
boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query resolver_query3{"www.google.com", "80"};
```

I'm compiling the code on centos with command: `sudo g++ main.cc boost-example.cc -o client -lboost_system -lpthread`
I checked the /etc/servies and it is exactly same as here: https://www.thegeekdiary.com/sample-etc-services-file-in-linux/.
Curl commands like: `curl https://www.google.com` works perfectly fine.
I have no idea what is going on.

Comment: Where do you run it? Does it have DNS? Does `ping www.google.com` also work? Because `curl` might be picking up a system-wide proxy configuration. `/etc/services` is not relevant because (a) you specify the service numerically (b) the message is "host not found" - not "service not found"

Comment: The ping doesn't work: `ping: google.com: Name or service not known`

Comment: There's your problem. Local resolver config is missing. Fix your network setup, or change the approach to use the same proxy.